# Select all values except repetitive

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have three tables.
First. Name: ExTable. Column: id(integer), name(text)

```
--------------------
|  id  |    name |
--------------------
|  1   |    exA    |
|  2   |    exB    |
|  3   |    exC    |
--------------------
```

Second: Name: CerTable. Column: id(integer), name(text)

```
-------------------
|  id  |    name  |
-------------------
|  1   |    first |
|  2   |    second|
|  3   |    third |
-------------------
```

Third: Name: CerExTable. Column: id(integer), id_cer(integer) from CerTable, id_ex(integer) - from ExTable.

```
----------------------------------
|  id  |      id_cer     | id_ex |
----------------------------------
|  1   |    1 (first)    |1 (exA)|
|  2   |    1 (first)    |2 (exB)|
|  3   |    1 (first)    |3 (exC)|
|  3   |    2 (second)   |1 (exA)|
|  3   |    2 (second)   |3 (exC)|
|  3   |    3 (third)    |2 (exB)|
---------------------------------
```

So, I want to select data with id_cer = 2 and id_ex !=(not equal!) 1 and 3. So, I want to get next value: exB. if id_cer=3, I want to get: exA, exC, If id_cer=1, I want to get null.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT ExTable.id, ExTable.name FROM ExTable, CerExTable WHERE CerExTable.id_cer = 2 AND CerExTable.id_ex != ExTable.id
```

Expected result:

```
--------------------
|  id  |    name   |
--------------------
|  2   |    exB    |
--------------------
```

But result is next:

```
--------------------
|  id  |    name   |
--------------------
|  2   |    exB    |
|  3   |    exC    |
|  1   |    exA    |
|  2   |    exB    |
--------------------
```

because this query get data firstly for "except exA" - exB, exC, and then "except  C" - exA, exB

How to get data exception instead of two lines(for example) "at one time"?

Comment: This is the second time you've posted this question, and I still can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish. I might not be smart enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your select putting an `*`you will see that you are really doing a more complex query. The result is:

`SELECT * FROM ExTable, CerExTable WHERE CerExTable.id_cer = 2 AND CerExTable.id_ex != ExTable.id;`

```
---------------------------------------------------
|      ExTable     |           CerExTable         |
---------------------------------------------------
|  id  |    name   |  id  |    id_cer   |  id_ex  |
---------------------------------------------------
|  2   |    exB    |   3  |      2      |    1    |
|  3   |    exC    |   3  |      2      |    1    |
|  1   |    exA    |   3  |      2      |    3    |
|  2   |    exB    |   3  |      2      |    3    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

All this rows satisfy the WHERE condition you are quering.

The solution to achive this result is to use 2 selects in the same query:

`SELECT * FROM ExTable WHERE ExTable.id NOT IN (SELECT CerExTable.id_ex FROM CerExTable WHERE CerExTable.id_cer = 2);`